# Add ssh verified fingerprint to known hosts

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, ssh-keys

I'm using Chef and trying to add an SSH fingerprint to the known_hosts file of a particular service user account so that I can pull in repos via git. My script is failing because the host verification failed. I do not want to skip verification. I'd like chef to install the fingerprint into the known hosts file.

Requirements:

1. Do not disable verification
2. Do not skip verification
3. Do not add duplicate entries to the known_hosts file (make it idempotent for chef)
4. Don't use DNS. SSH can use DNS for verification, but this isn't overly secure and it's not enabled by default for installs.
5. Make it easy to change later, don't pre-compile the hashed line for known_hosts, the input should be an ssh key's fingerprint.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I've been looking at ssh-keyscan and ssh-keygen. There are search functions and remove functions, but no method to add a key, so it seems.

Comment: See: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts. See also: https://sethvargo.com/add-ssh-known-hosts-with-chef/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ssh` cookbook from the supermarket.  https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh

it has an LWRP that makes adding the keys very easy.

Comment: So, I just tried it. Two problems. One, it requires that the line is provided for you (violates requirement 5) and appears to be inserting duplicate rows (#3).

Comment: Take a look at the readme.  There is a `hashed` attribute which defaults to `true`, but you can set it to false if you prefer.  As for the duplicates, it has been tested pretty heavily.  Double check, and if you are getting duplicates, put in an issue with an example that can be used to re-produce.  I'll be sure to get it patched.

Comment: I'd like to keep the entries hashed. As for the test case, I used it as directed by the docs. Every chef-client run adds 2 entries to the known_hosts file. Always.

Comment: @Chris I believe this was patched quite some time ago.  If you run the kitchen test and then re-converge a few times, you still only get one copy of each key.